# Add image as label on plotline highcharts

Tags: highcharts

I am experiencing some mis-alignment on the image I added as label, this issue occurs sometimes during refresh. How can I prevent it from occuring ?

[image]

Here is my code:

```
  plotLines: [{
    color: '#FF0000',
    width: 2,
    value: 5.5,
    modifyPath: function(path) {
      return path;
    },
    label: {
      text: '<img src="https://s19.postimg.org/e88q9y8fn/finish.png">',
      align: 'center',
      verticalAlign: 'bottom',
      textAlign: 'center',
      //x: -10,
      y: -13,
      rotation: 360,
      useHTML: true
    }

  }]
```

This is my sample jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/dd5d7roh/

Comment: use `x:0` check http://jsfiddle.net/hanawff2/

Comment: x:0 doesn't assure you that it would be aligned. I tested that

Comment: It seems to be a bug. I reported it here: https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/issues/7468